# How to retrieve an URL inside a .NET http handler?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I'm hosting images on a server, within an ASP.NET application.
I wrote a custom http handler that resizes the image and also increment "image_view_count" in a DB.

Now, I would like to also do some logging to know where the image is used. For example:

Image abc.jpg is on my server at www.myserver.com/stuff/abc.jpg
Somebody uses it by linking it in a forum post located at www.forum.com/thread.php?id=1234

I would like to retrieve the www.forum.com/thread.php?id=1234 URL in my http handler. When I use Request.Url.ToString(), in the previous example, I receive www.myserver.com/stuff/abc.jpg.

How should I do this ? Is there an equivalent in managed code to location.href ?

Comment: Have you tried the Referrer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *believe* you're looking for the `Referer` header.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
  IServiceProvider provider = (IServiceProvider)context;
  HttpWorkerRequest worker = (HttpWorkerRequest)provider.GetService(typeof(HttpWorkerRequest));
  String referer = worker.GetKnownRequestHeader(HttpWorkerRequest.HeaderReferer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Request.Url is the url for the current request - ie, the request to load your image.

You may be able to get what you want by checking the [Referer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx), however this is not always reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check referer to see where the image is used:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

C#

```
string referer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

UrlReferrer can be null if the browser is not sending referer in request header.